# Grouping by large number of columns with ordinal reference

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a lengthy query in postgres that requires grouping by 30 different columns referenced in the query

At the moment, I have manually listed the `group by` columns by their ordinal value in the query

```
SELECT ...
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

Does a better way of doing this exist? I have tried

```
SELECT...
GROUP BY array(generate_series(1, 30))
```

But this method fails.  Is there a way to use `generate_series` in the `GROUP BY` clause to reference columns in the query in cases where queries require a large number of `group by` columns?

Comment: You need to list the columns explicitly.  Now . . . *why* you have to group by so many columns is suspicious.  I suspect there are better ways to write the query.

Comment: I agree with Gordon: grouping by so many columns is a code smell. It's highly likely that you are tackling the problem from the wrong side.

Comment: a real use case that I'm doing - create an analytical cube which requires all possible dimensions in group by. @GordonLinoff